# Existence and uniqueness of geodesics in low regularity

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, regularity, geodesics, uniqueness-theorems

Consider a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$.
How much regularity is required of $g$ so that for any $x\in M$ and $v\in T_xM$ with $|v|=1$ there exists a unique geodesic $\gamma\colon(-\epsilon,\epsilon)\to M$ so that $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\dot\gamma(0)=v$?
All regularity is considered with respect to a fixed smooth (or somewhat less regular) atlas or (equivalently) in a fixed local coordinate chart.

If $g\in C^{1,1}$, then the Christoffel symbol is Lipschitz, whence existence and uniqueness follows from standard ODE theory.
For ODEs in general Lipschitz continuity is sufficient and necessary for existence and uniqueness.
It is not clear to me whether this is the case for geodesics, because the geodesic equation has a very specific structure and that may provide uniqueness in even lower regularity.

Existence requires less regularity than uniqueness, and [this old question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/133724/55893) is about existence for continuous metrics.
Since existence is known in very low regularity, my question concerns uniqueness (although I want to have both existence and uniqueness in as low regularity as possible).
If a metric can have a jump discontinuity, then both existence and uniqueness can be made fail, but I am not aware of any smoother counterexamples.

A refined (but equivalent) version my question is: *What are the best sufficient and necessary regularity conditions we know (whether or not they coincide in our current knowledge) on a Riemannian metric for **uniqueness** of geodesics?*
I am not aware of any positive or negative uniqueness results for $C^{0,\alpha}$ or $C^{1,\alpha}$ below $C^{1,1}$.
For example, are geodesics unique if $g\in C^{1,\alpha}$ for some $\alpha>0$, or are there perhaps counterexamples for all $\alpha<1$?
If you find the question unclear, please ask for details.

At least for $g\in C^1$ the geodesic equation is a well-defined classical ODE.
I guess that satisfying the geodesic equation and minimizing arc length locally are equivalent in this regularity, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Maybe it helps to imagine a twodimensional flat cone. Here, geodesics going into the tip have no unique continuation. So it might be an interesting question which coordinates on the flattened cone produce $g$ with maxium regularity, and if this regularity depends on the angle. Anyway, you would get a lower bound for your question.

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question? I find it very interesting and important in my research.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz I did now; see the answer below. It seems that uniqueness is not guaranteed for $g\in C^{1,\alpha}$ for $\alpha<1$, so the naive assumption $g\in C^{1,1}$ is pretty sharp.

Comment: In some sense, regularity of the metric is not the right condition to use, since it is coordinate-dependent. You want to distinguish between metrics that are smooth with respect to some coordinate system and metrics that are not smooth in every coordinate system. Perhaps one should consider generalized curvature bounds, defined in terms of geodesic triangles (i.e., the distances between 3 points).

Comment: @DeaneYang That seems to depend on the regularity of the atlas. If the transition functions are smooth, a $C^{1,\alpha}$ metric in some coordinates is also $C^{1,\alpha}$ in any other coordinates, so regularity of the metric is invariant. (Or did I miss something?) If the atlas has less regularity than the metric, then regularity is indeed coordinate-dependent.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, I don't see why with a metric that is smooth with respect to a smooth atlas, there couldn't be a bad atlas that has smooth transition functions but where the components of the metric tensor are not smooth with respect to that atlas.

Comment: In fact, that's why harmonic coordinates are so important in Riemannian geometry. The regularity of the metric tensor is best with respect to harmonic coordinates versus any other ones.

Comment: @DeaneYang Yes, regularity may vary between different atlases, but given a fixed atlas (which I considered here to come with a Riemannian manifold), regularity of the metric is invariant. Pretty much all regularity can change when you change an atlas, but not when you change coordinates within a smooth atlas. Smoothness depends on the smooth structure, and meant to work within a fixed atlas.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, here's the somewhat confusing situation. It is known that if there is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism between two smooth manifolds, then there exists a $C^\infty$ diffeomorphism. So if you apply a $C^1$ but non-smooth diffeomorphism to a smooth Riemannian manifold, you get a $C^0$ Riemannian metric on the same smooth manifold.

Comment: I think the issue about harmonic coordinates is that if your metric is $C^{k,\alpha}$ in some local coordinates, not necessarily with respect to a smooth atlas, then in harmonic coordinates it is $C^{k+1,\alpha}$. However, if the metric is $C^{k,\alpha}$ in a chart, then it is $C^{k,\alpha}$ in harmonic coordinates. As compared for example to normal coordinates where the metric is only $C^{k-2,\alpha}$.

Comment: @C_S, there's no need to discuss atlases here, because everything is local. The question I'm addressing is the regularity of the metric with respect to local coordinates. If there exist local coordinates in which the metric is, say, $C^2$, even if those coordinates are only $C^1$ with respect to whatever local coordinates you started with, then existence and uniqueness of geodesic holds with respect to any set of coordinates that are $C^1$ functions of the original coordinates.

Comment: The way I think of it is that the Riemannian metric is well-defined and continuous independent of any choice of coordinates as long as one set of coordinates consists of $C^1$ functions of another set of coordinates. The existence and uniqueness of geodesic is a property of the Riemannian metric, independent of the local coordinates, because it is defined using only lengths (or energies) of curves.

Comment: @DeaneYang, I agree. I tried to clear up some of the confusion about which statements are just local (irrespective of the atlas) and which are not. Moreover, I am still sure that you can define the regularity of e.g. a metric independently of coordinates.

Comment: @C_S, I'd be interested in your thoughts about defining the regularity of a metric independent of coordinates. You can, of course, define it, but how would you determine the regularity of any given metric? As far as I know, the best that's known is that, if you assume something like an $L^p$ bound on the curvature, then the best possible regularity of the metric, namely $W^{p,2}$, is achieved using harmonic coordinates. Without the curvature tensor, I think you have to assume bounds on a proxy for curvature, such as the angle defect of small geodesic triangles.

Comment: I think it should work like that: By using harmonic coordinates you can determine the minimal regularity of a given metric. So you take a chart (of your atlas), go to harmonic coordinates, read off the regularity. Then you know that you cannot do better than that in any other chart. (I don't have any references at hand at the moment. I will try to find something useful next week).

Comment: @C_S and Deane Yang: That is an interesting discussion that I will be happy to follow, but tangential to the question at hand. I edited the question to elaborate on what regularity means to me here.

Comment: @DeaneYang As an afterthought: I think we are not talking about the same thing. For me a (Riemannian) manifold comes with its smooth structure. Charts and regularity are defined with respect to this. In this setting you cannot do better than by using harmonic coordinates. But this does not mean that there is another smooth structure where the regularity is better. And this seems to be what you mean.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a classical example by Hartman that shows failure of uniqueness for $C^{1,\alpha}$ metrics. (P. Hartman, On the local uniqueness of geodesics, Amer. J. Math. 1950).

You could lower the regularity if the metric is smooth off some hypersurface but globally only $C^{0,1}$, see for example our recent review: [On geodesics in low regularity](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/968/1/012010)

Moreover, being minimzing and solving the geodesic equations is not the same below $C^{1,1}$; see also Hartman or our review.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that [Hartman's paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2372288) gives an example of non-uniqueness for $g\in C^{1,1/3}$ in dimension two. It can probably be made work for any $\alpha<1$, but I didn't see it in the paper. That review looks like an excellent resource on the topic.

Comment: Yes, it works for any $\alpha<1$. See also P. Hartman and A. Wintner. On the problems of geodesics in the small. Amer.  J.  Math. , 73:132–148, 1951 or Ex. 2.1 in our review.